# log4j duplicate messages when using AsyncAppender

Tags: scala, asynchronous, log4j2

I'm writing an app which uses log4j 2.5 and everything worked great. To improve performance, I wanted to make logger async but didn't want to add the disruptor dependency so I decided to use Async Appenders. I found some examples of how to use them, but I guess something went wrong in the process :(

I'm not using an xml config file, but instead create all my loggers in the code. What I'm doing is first create my appenders and afterwards I create Async Appenders for each one of them where I reference their name.

Am I getting duplicate messages because for each appender I've got both the appender itself and also an AsyncAppender sending my messages to that appender?

My code:

```
addAppenderToLogger(fileAppender, logger)
addAppenderToLogger(rollingFileAppender, logger)

AsyncAppender.createAppender(
  names.map(name => AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(
    name, Level.getLevel("INFO"), null
  )), errorRef, true, 0, 2048, s"async-appender", false, null, config, true
)
```

I'm creating 1 AsyncAppender for both my appenders.

Example for duplicate logs:

> 2017-01-26 13:21:33,619 [Executor task launch worker-1] INFO
>   short-text - Starting to tag ID 973376
>
> 2017-01-26 13:21:33,619 [Executor task launch worker-2] INFO
>   short-text - Starting to tag ID 2497995
>
> 2017-01-26 13:21:33,619 [Executor task launch worker-1] INFO
>   short-text - Starting to tag ID 973376
>
> 2017-01-26 13:21:33,619 [Executor task launch worker-2] INFO
>   short-text - Starting to tag ID 2497995

Answer (score 0):

If you add both the FileAppender and the AsyncAppender to your logger directly, then this will become the bottleneck and you lose the benefit of asynchronous logging.

Add *only* the AsyncAppender to your loggers and let the AsyncAppender point to the FileAppender via an AppenderRef.

---

As for programmatic configuration, some Log4j2 tests are doing something similar to what you are trying to do. For example [this one](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/dd943975b7c809c3d302237cecf7116c9c9e9ea2/log4j-core/src/test/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/WriterAppenderTest.java):

```
final LoggerContext context = LoggerContext.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
final PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout(config);
final Appender appender = WriterAppender.createAppender(layout, null, writer, writerName, false, true);
appender.start();
config.addAppender(appender);

final Level level = null;
final Filter filter = null;
for (final LoggerConfig loggerConfig : config.getLoggers().values()) {
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, level, filter);
}
config.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender, level, filter);
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: What I did before, was creating the appenders and adding them to the logger, afterwards creating an Async Appender with `AppenderRefs` and then removing the original appenders. That seemed to work but it is a pretty ugly solution (creating and then removing). I now tried what you did but I get a NullPointerException. Where should I create the appenders? In the main Logger? And the AsyncAppender I create in my app's context logger? Because just creating them as variables isn't enough (creates a NullPointerException)

Comment: The root logger should refer to the AsyncAppender, and the AsyncAppender should refer to the FileAppender. Other loggers obtained from the same LoggerContext (~1 on 1 with application) will route events to their parent logger (the root logger).

Comment: But how can I make my AsyncAppender refer to the FileAppender if he wasn't registered with any logger/context?

For example:

    val fileAppender = createFileAppender(name)
    val rollingFileAppender = createRollingFileAppender(name, folderNameExt)

    val curLogger = ctx.getLogger(name)
    addAppenderToLogger(createAsyncAdapter(Array(fileAppender.getName, rollingFileAppender.getName), fileAppender.getName), curLogger)

    ctx.getLogger(name).setLevel(Level.ALL)

results in a NullPointerException because at runtime, the createAsyncAdapter doesn't know the Appender's names

Comment: Updated answer with example. There may be more tests like this in the log4j2 code base.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it. And you didn't use an AsyncAppender in your example  so I still don't understand how to add both the FileAppender and the AsyncAppender with the AppenderRef, without adding the FileAppender itself. Should I add the FileAppender to the `config` variable, and the AsyncAppender to my actual Logger?

Comment: Yes both the FileAppender and the AsyncAppender should be added to the Configuration. FileAppender needs to be added to the AsyncAppender. Make sure to call start() on all appenders. Finally use addAppender to add AsyncAppender to all loggerConfigs (incl root).